# How to check progress of ElasticSearch's Reindex API

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, reindex

I'm trying to execute a reindex operation from remote ES 2.4 cluster via **Reindex API**. Which job is to transfer more then 100 million docs of an index to latest version of elasticsearch.

For the test case i'm trying it on small data set but i'm facing following issues.

**issue:**

1. I can't see the progress of the of the script that how many docs are
   transfered and how many left.
2. In case of failure, How can i resume the script instead of
   restarting again from 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Task management API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html) to know the status of `reindex`, As suggested in the [official doc of reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-task-api). from the same doc

> If the request contains wait_for_completion=false, Elasticsearch
> performs some preflight checks, launches the request, and **returns a
> task you can use to cancel or get the status of the task.**
> Elasticsearch creates a record of this task as a document at
> .tasks/_doc/${taskId}. When you are done with a task, you should
> delete the task document so Elasticsearch can reclaim the space.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. but does it handle the second case as well ? In case of failure at any point remaining docs can be resume or would need to execute from 0 again ?

Comment: @WaqasAfzal not all errors you can handle, please refer the `error` section of reindex API for more info, `(array) Array of failures if there were any unrecoverable errors during the process. If this is non-empty then the request aborted because of those failures. Reindex is implemented using batches and any failure causes the entire process to abort but all failures in the current batch are collected into the array. You can use the conflicts option to prevent reindex from aborting on version conflicts.`

Comment: @WaqasAfzal you can also have a look at Kiabana upgrade assistent API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/start-resume-reindex.html but this is in experimental phase, but good part its part of basic license

Comment: I don't think that kibana reindex api allow to reindex from remote ES 2.4 cluster.

Comment: but for me native ElasticSearch Reindex API from remote enabled me to trasfer data from es2 to es7. Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225204/discussion-between-elasticsearch-ninja-and-waqas-afzal).